# Shuffling elements in an array when 'priority' values are the same?

Tags: php

I have a keyed array, each slot containing two pieces of information: a company name and a priority. I am trying to find a way to shuffle company names that have the same priority value. I am familiar with the shuffle function, however, I don't want to shuffle all elements in the array ignoring the priority values, I would like to ONLY shuffle element that have the same priority value.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

**Note:** all the following element are in the same array

```
    McDonalds, 10
    Marshalls, 10
    Dillards,  10
    Burger King, 5
    Hunan Palace, 5
    Taco Bell, 5
    Pizza Hut, 5
    Macy's, 2
    Prudential, 2
    Nike, 2
    Billabong, 2
```

I would like to end up with something like:

```
        Marshalls, 10
        Dillards,  10
        McDonalds, 10
        Hunan Palace, 5
        Burger King, 5
        Pizza Hut, 5
        Taco Bell, 5
        Nike, 2
        Macy's, 2
        Billabong, 2
        Prudential, 2
```

Comment: Put it in a database and write a query. Or use `usort` http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: shuffle($myArray); however, this will shuffle all elements, while ignoring priority values, which is not what I want...

Comment: @bigman I am already using usort to sort by order of priority... please elaborate as to how this will help me solve the problem described above.

Comment: Oh you're already using that, nice of you to mention it.  Post some code.

Comment: shuffle and after that usort.

Comment: @UAWDT your suggestion is simple and effective! post an answer so I can pick your answer as the solution :) thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to shuffle and after that usort

**Edit**

```
$array = array(
   array('company' => 'McDonalds', 'priority' => 10),
   array('company' => 'Marshalls', 'priority' => 10),
   //...
);

shuffle($array); //shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array

function custom_sort($left, $right) {
    return $right['priority'] - $left['priority'];
}

usort($array, "custom_sort"); // sort by user-defined comparison function
```

[shuffle man](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)
[usort man](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 1):

While sorting with `usort`, when you have equal priories, sort by random facotr added to each element in your array:

```
$myArray = array(
   array('company' => 'McDonalds', 'priority' => 10),
   array('company' => 'Marshalls', 'priority' => 10),
);

foreach($myArray as &$elem){
    //add new property
    $elem['random_factor'] = rand(0,65535);
}
```

And now sort by priority, and next by random factor:

```
function sort_and_shuffle($a,$b){
    if($a['priority'] == $b['priority']){
        if($a['random_factor'] == $b['random_factor']){
            return 0;
        }
        return return ($a['random_factor'] < $b['random_factor']) ? -1 : 1;
    }else{
        return return ($a['priority'] > $b['priority']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Don't try returning random result on each equal priority like below:

```
function sort_and_shuffle($a,$b){
    if($a['priority'] == $b['priority']){
        return rand(-1,1);
    }else{
        return return ($a['priority'] > $b['priority']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

It is inefficient and in worst case scenario it can run forever, since there is no constant result when comparing same elements

Comment: The first approach breaks the invariant of the comparer, which means that the sort is also within its rights to break its own promises --  for example it may decide to run forever. I really feel it should be an example of what *not* to do instead of part of your answer.

Comment: @Jon that's what I wanted to say, but now looking at my answer I see that it is not clearly explained, thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, that avoids you having to mess with your data.  Start with your basic `usort()` call.

```
$places = array(
    array('name'=>'Marshalls', 'priority'=>10),
    array('name'=>'Pizza Hut', 'priority'=>5),
    ...
);

usort($places, function($left, $right) {
    return $right['priority'] - $left['priority'];
});
```

Now you need a function that will take a small array, shuffle it, and append it to a larger array.

```
function shuffleAndAppend(&$temp, &$final) {
    shuffle($temp);
    array_splice($final, count($final), 0, $temp);
    $temp = array();
}
```

Now you can loop through your sorted array and group together the items with same priority, shuffle them, and then append them to the final array.

```
$shuffledPlaces = array();
$tempPlaces = array();
$lastPriority = -1;

foreach ($places as $onePlace) {
    if ($onePlace['priority'] != $lastPriority)
        shuffleAndAppend($tempPlaces, $shuffledPlaces);
    array_push($tempPlaces, $onePlace);
    $lastPriority = $onePlace['priority'];
}
shuffleAndAppend($tempPlaces, $shuffledPlaces);

print_r($shuffledPlaces);
```